# Looping through JSON Data

Tags: php

There is probably a simple response to this, but I've scoured the net trying to find an answer.

Imagine the following JSON data ($json):

```
{'Top': [{  'Mid1': 'Value1',
            'Mid2': 'Value2',
            'Mid3': [   {'Bottom': 'Value3'},
                        {'Bottom': 'Value4'},
                        {'Bottom': 'Value5'},]
        }]}
```

What I'd like to do is loop through the data contained within Mid3, so that I can display Bottom1, Bottom2, etc.. so I thought this would work:

```
foreach($json->Top->Mid3 as $item)
{
echo $item->Bottom;
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach is looking for Mid3 elements and not there child nodes.

Use:

```
foreach($json->Top->Mid3->Bottom as $item)
{
   echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually had it right, but didn't manage to solve more detailed ones, i.e. a group within a group within a group, etc.. where the information is quite deep. Still trying to figure out how to use ...->group[0]->... but running into walls to finally get to my chunk of information (which I want to loop).